# Adding a second to timer when icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my number game children have 30 seconds to shoot the number icons that realate to a given question like "even numbers". I have recently added two clock icons as a bonus. When they shoot the blue one it will add 3 seconds and shooting the red one will take off 3 seconds.

At the moment the clocks are assumed as wrong but I because of the if statement below. Is there a way I can incorporate the clocks into this click function, or will I have to start a new one? Also how do I add and take seconds from the timer?

```
    $(".character").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("wrong")) {
        $(this).effect("bounce", {
            times: 2,
            direction: 'left'
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).slideUp("fast")
        });
        miss++;
        attempted++;
        $("#miss").html("Wrong: " + miss);
    } else {
        $(this).effect("explode", 300);
        hit++;
        attempted++;
        $("#hit").html("Right: " + hit);
    }
});
});
```

Here is the list of icons

```
<ul id="container">
    <li><div id="char1" class="character right" vaule="1"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char2" class="character right" vaule="2"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char3" class="character right" vaule="3"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char4" class="character right" vaule="4"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char5" class="character right" vaule="5"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char6" class="character right" vaule="6"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char7" class="character right" vaule="7"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char8" class="character right" vaule="8"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char9" class="character right" vaule="9"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char10" class="character right" vaule="0"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char11" class="character clock up"></div></li>
    <li><div id="char12" class="character clock down"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cFKHq/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played around with your fiddle (forked it: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/1/) and I think I made it work. I changed that if loop to the following, and it alters the global count variable if one of the clocks is clicked. it will only go and check for right or wrong if there is no clock found.

```
$(".character").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clock")) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("up")) {
                $(this).effect("explode", 300);
                count += 3;
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("down")) {
                $(this).effect("bounce", {
                    times: 2,
                    direction: 'left'
                }, 300, function() {
                    $(this).slideUp("fast")
                });
                count -= 3;
            }
            $('#timer').text(count);
        } else {
            if ($(this).hasClass("wrong")) {
                $(this).effect("bounce", {
                    times: 2,
                    direction: 'left'
                }, 300, function() {
                    $(this).slideUp("fast")
                });
                miss++;
                attempted++;
                $("#miss").html("Wrong: " + miss);
            } else {
                $(this).effect("explode", 300);
                hit++;
                attempted++;
                $("#hit").html("Right: " + hit);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: made another small edit: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/2/, need to check for count to be 0 or less, because it can go as low as -2 because of those clocks.

Comment: Ok since I saw in another comment you didn't give the latest fiddle I changed it again to match your latest version: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/3/

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a timer event that is independent of your animation. `setInterval` will call itself based on the amount of time specified, in this case, 1000ms.

```
var timeLeft = 30;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    timeLeft--;
    if(timeLeft<1) {
        clearTimeout(timer)        
        alert("finished");
        return;        
    }
    $('#time').html(timeLeft);
},1000)

function adjTime(amt) {
    timeLeft = timeLeft + amt
   if(timeLeft<1) {
        clearTimeout(timer)        
        alert("finished");
        return;
    }
    $('#time').html(timeLeft);
}
```

Test HTML:

```
<div id="time"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="adjTime(3)" value="Add 3 sec" />
<input type="button" onclick="adjTime(-3)" value="Subtract 3 sec" />
```

Comment: So would I be making the clocks into buttons? Have you got a fiddle to show? @Diodeus

Comment: The buttons are there just to demonstrate how the code works. You need to call the same functions in your code, based on the game logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the timer count as a global.

http://jsfiddle.net/mdc5X/

Instead of count, I declared it as

```
var game = {
    count: 30,
}
```

and modified every instance of count to game.count

Then, you can simply do

```
game.count += 5 // to add time
game.count -+ 5 // to remove time
```

Of course, this is not secure (anyone with a console could simply type game.count = 1000), but it should be okay for a children's game.

The correct way of doing this would be with private members. You can read more about it here: (http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)

Comment: But that would make all right and wrong answers affect the time @Aktee

Comment: Yes, in the fiddle that I did it would make all right and wrong answers to affect the time. Just move the conditions

Comment: @Milo-J, it's hard to do a correct jsfiddle because you did not define  CSS for char11 and char12. Do it, and I'll give you the correct code.

Comment: Oh sorry I seem to have given the previous fiddle try number 15 @Aktee